# How to get Contact's Nickname Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Using Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactManager and ContactStore I can read all or search for contacts (People) with FindContactAsync(...). On some records I have only Nickname field set under Name (in People/phonebook) group. They are returned when I search for their Nickname but all Name related fields from Contact instance are string empty. I couldn't find any nickname field on that type either.

Is there any way to get the contact Nickname on Windows Phone 8.1 (NOT Silverlight)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime app recently and also came upon this same issue.

It seems that the Nickname property of the Contact class has been documented by Microsoft, but not yet implemented into Visual Studio for other developers to use.

You can see all the properties for the Contact class here:
[Contact class - Windows app development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contact.aspx)

And the details for Nickname property here:
[Contact.Nickname | nickname property - Windows app development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contact.nickname.aspx)

Check the property page.  A message says it's not released and the requirements are Windows 10.

It does seem strange that users can enter a Nickname in the People app, but we as other developers can't use it in our own apps.  I guess that's just the way it is for now with Windows Phone 8.1 custom apps.

Comment: From the property page documentation "[Some information relates to pre-released product which may be substantially modified before it's commercially released. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied, with respect to the information provided here.]" :).

Comment: That is correct.  I think this answers your question.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not see how it answers to my question. I totally agree that in the meantime MS added the property and document it for Windows 10, but as I see the property is not available in WP8.1. I'm still unable to get the Nickname stored in WP8.1 People contacts.

Comment: As far as I know after much research it's just not possible at this time.  The answer is that there is currently no way to do it.