# How to get NickName property form a Saved Contact in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to show all contacts in my windows phone with their fields. (Eg: Name,DisplayName,NickName etc..)
I 'm able to get all properties from my Contact. But i'm unable to find 'NickName' property in my contact.
Please help me to get NickName property from a Contact.
please find this code for reference,

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=391641

namespace ConatctsTestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.
        }
        private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string searchText = "";
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactStore contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();

            IReadOnlyList<Contact> contacts = null;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
            {
                // Find all contacts
                contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                // Find contacts based on a search string
                contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync(searchText);
            }

            for (int c = 0; c < contacts.Count; c++)
            {                
                    string impdate = "";

                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts[c].ImportantDates.Count; i++)
                    {
                        impdate = impdate + contacts[c].DisplayName + "\n";
                        ContactDateKind kind = contacts[c].ImportantDates[i].Kind;

                        impdate = impdate + kind.ToString() + "\n";
                        impdate = impdate + (contacts[c].ImportantDates[i].Day.Value + 1).ToString() +
                                      "." + contacts[c].ImportantDates[i].Month.Value.ToString() +
                                      "." + contacts[c].ImportantDates[i].Year.Value.ToString();
                        impdate = impdate + "\n";
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts[c].Websites.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //Count 0
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts[c].Addresses.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string addressKind = contacts[c].Addresses[i].Kind.ToString();
                    }                
                //MessageBox.Show(impdate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. I clearly see a `Nickname` property on the `Contact` class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contact.aspx

Comment: I want to get Nickname from a Contact. I did not find any property for Nickname in Contact class. we have Nickname property in Extended properties. i can assign  Nickname to a Contact while creating like this,

            StoredContact contact = null;
                var contactProperties = await contact.GetPropertiesAsync();
  contactProperties[KnownContactProperties.Nickname]
                  = "Matt";

But i'm unable to retrieve the Nickname property from a Contact that is Contact List of Windows phone.

Comment: Interesting. I spun up a quick test application and I see the problem you are having. Even though the documentation indicates that the `Contact` class has a `Nickname` property it is not there. I decompiled `Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact` and the property simply is not there. You're not the only one experiencing this problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942269/how-to-get-contacts-nickname-windows-phone-8-1, and unfortunately I'm not seeing a solution. Wish I could help more.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime app recently and also came upon this same issue.

I just answered a similar older post here:
[How to get Contact's Nickname Windows Phone 8.1 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942269/how-to-get-contacts-nickname-windows-phone-8-1)

It seems that the Nickname property of the Contact class has been documented by Microsoft, but not yet implemented into Visual Studio for other developers to use.

You can see all the properties for the Contact class here:
[Contact class - Windows app development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contact.aspx)

And the details for Nickname property here:
[Contact.Nickname | nickname property - Windows app development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contact.nickname.aspx)

Check the property page.  A message says it's not released and the requirements are Windows 10.

It does seem strange that users can enter a Nickname in the People app, but we as other developers can't use it in our own apps.  I guess that's just the way it is for now with Windows Phone 8.1 custom apps.